# java FileChannel writing to a file and adding \n at the end

Tags: java, file-io, file-processing, filechannel

i'm trying to make log using the FileChannel.
for some reason it doesn't get the \n character in my file.

my function:

```
private void serverLog(String status, String message)
    {           
        currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        String date = dateFormat.format(currentTime);
        String time = timeFormat.format(currentTime);
        String log = logFileName + date + "-" + time;
        String path = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
        String logLine = date + "|" + time + "|" + status + "|" + message + "|" + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() + "\n"; 
        File file = new File(path,log);

        try {
            if (!file.exists())                 
                file.createNewFile();
            fileChannel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();                
            FileLock lock = fileChannel.tryLock();

            while (!lock.isValid())
                lock = fileChannel.tryLock();

            if (lock.isValid())
            {
                fileChannel.position(fileChannel.size());
                ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(logLine.length());
                buf.clear();
                buf.put(logLine.getBytes());
                buf.flip();
                while (buf.hasRemaining())
                    fileChannel.write(buf);     
                lock.release();
                fileChannel.close();
            }   

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
```

this is my output file:

```
16-05-2012|20-17-27|Success|New user connected: Id: 12345 Name: asaf IP: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|8154448016-05-2012|20-17-27|Count|Current users online: 1, Current ghosts connections: 0|81544480
```

Comment: Where do you want `\n` character ?

Comment: What happens when you log two lines?

Comment: you see in my log that i logged 2 lines, and you can see that in my serverLog function i have \n in the end of the logLine

Comment: Try this: public static final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

Comment: Remove `if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();`: creating the RandomAccessFile in the next line already does that. Don't spin in `tryLock()`: use `lock()` and block until you get it. You're really doing this the hard way. You could do most of it with new FileWriter(xxx, true) to append to the file.